# I am not able to debug Android Native Browser using Chrome Remote Debug

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I am not able to debug Android Native Browser using Chrome Remote Debug,
But i am able to debug Chrome browser(in android phone) html pages

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [doc](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#requirements) you need to have **Chrome for Android**